# Meaning of the word 한전쯤

Tags: word-choice

Could anyone explain this word? I can't find the meaning even in Korean dictionaries. Is it 한번쯤?

I saw this from a sentence:

확실하지 않은데 한전쯤은 잘 거 같다.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a typo. If it is "한번쯤" then it makes sense. Where do you see its sentence?

Comment: If it is 한번쯤 what does this sentence mean? "Not sure but I will sleep once" is it this meaning?

Answer (score 2):

한전쯤 does not make sense.

Based in the context in your sentence, it should be 한번쯤 meaning approximately once.

So the sentence can translate to "I'm not sure, will probably sleep once."

Another example of 한번쯤: 누구나 일생에 한번쯤은 거짓말을 한다: everyone lies at least once in their life.